# I need help saving a MultipartFile in spring MVC to a SMB network drive

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to save a MultipartFile (uploaded to Spring MVC controller) to a  linux server on the network (requires authentication).  I tried smb using jcifs but the performance is very poor.

Could someone point me to an alternate way of doing this?  I searched everywhere for 2 days and have not been able to find a solution that works.

The application server runs linux.

Edit:  This is the code I am using.  The code works but performs very, very poorly

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFileInputStream;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream;

@Component
public class FileUploadUtil {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileUploadUtil.class);

    @Value("${dr.fileuser}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${dr.filepwd}")
    private String pass;

    @Value("${dr.sharePath}")
    private String drSharePath;

    @Value("${dr.fileLocation}")
    private String drFileLocation;

    @Value("${dr.serverName}")
    private String drServerName;


    /**
     * @param uploadedFile
     * @param filename
     * @param discId: this is a generated id, used to associate these files with a database record.
     * @return
     * @throws WW_Exception
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String writeFileToServer(MultipartFile uploadedFile, String filename, Integer discId) throws WW_Exception, IOException   {

        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("",user, pass);

        String destDir = StringUtils.cleanPath("smb://" + drServerName + drSharePath + drFileLocation + discId + "/");

        LOGGER.info("FILE Destination DIR: {}", destDir);
        try{
            //create directory structure
            SmbFile sfileDir = new SmbFile(destDir, auth);
            if(!sfileDir.exists()) {
                sfileDir.mkdirs();
            }

            String destFilePath = StringUtils.cleanPath(destDir + filename);
            LOGGER.info("FILE Destination PATH: {}", destFilePath);
            SmbFile sfile = new SmbFile(destFilePath, auth);
            try (SmbFileOutputStream fos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sfile)){
                fos.write(uploadedFile.getBytes());
            }

            return destFilePath.replace("smb:", "");

        } catch(Exception e){
            throw e;
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param drId: this is a generated id, used to associate these files with a database record.
     * @param origFilePath
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String copyFileFromServer(Integer drId, String origFilePath) throws  IOException   {

        LOGGER.info("FILE to get: {}",origFilePath);

        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("",user, pass);

        String[] imagePathInfo = origFilePath.split("/");
        String destFilePath = StringUtils.cleanPath("/weblogs/tmp/" + drId + "/" + imagePathInfo[imagePathInfo.length-1]);

        File destDir = new File(StringUtils.cleanPath("/weblogs/tmp/" + drId + "/"));
        if(!destDir.exists()) {
            destDir.mkdirs();
        }

        SmbFile origFile = new SmbFile(origFilePath,auth);
        try(InputStream in = new SmbFileInputStream(origFile)) {
             Files.copy(in, Paths.get(destFilePath), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }

        return destFilePath;

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jorge, do you have root access on the server in question?

Comment: Also, are you trying to associate this uploaded content with Spring Data entities or something like that or simply just storing the file at a known path on the server for later retrieval?

Comment: Hi @PaulWarren, I can get root access to the server.  I am just trying to save the file for later retrieval.  Right now using jcifs is taking about 8 seconds to store a 8MB file which is too long. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jorge,

Based on your comments above as you have root access to the linux server then I  all you need to do is a regular old kernel mount.  You will need to ensure that you have installed the cifs client (assuming ubuntu):

```
$ sudo apt install -y cifs-utils
```

Then you should be able to mount your share with something like:

```
$ SMB_USERNAME=<your username>
$ SMB_PASSWORD=<your password>
$ SMB_SERVER="//<your host>/<your share>"
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=${SMB_USERNAME},password=${SMB_PASSWORD} \
       "${SMB_SERVER}" /mnt
```

Then option 1 would be to modify your code to read and write files to the mounted directory; i.e. `/mnt` in this case.

Or, option 2, would be to use the community project called [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  This provides an abstraction over storage for resource handling and can inject the controller and service code for you so that you don't need to write it yourself.  One of the supported storage modules is the Filesystem Storage module and you would configure this to read and write files to your local `/mnt` directory which is really your remote share.

So, if you added Spring Content to your project you could remove all of your controller code and not worry about the implementation details.  Plus, as Spring Content is an abstraction, in future, you could also shift to any of the other storage mediums supported by Spring Content; S3 for example.   Adding it would look something like this:

> pom.xml (assuming maven.  Spring boot starters also available)

```
    <!-- Java API -->
    <!-- just change this depdendency if you want to store somewhere else -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-fs</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- REST API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-rest</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

> StoreConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableFilesystemStores
@Import(RestConfiguration.class)
public class StoreConfig {

    @Bean
    FileSystemResourceLoader fileSystemResourceLoader() throws IOException {
        return new FileSystemResourceLoader(new File("/mnt").getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

> FileStore.java

```
  @StoreRestResource(path="files")
  public interface FileStore extends Store<String> {
  }
```

And that's it.  The FileStore is essentially a generic Spring ResourceLoader.  The `spring-content-fs`  dependency will cause Spring Content to inject a filesystem-based implementation so you don't need to worry about implementing it yourself.  Moreover, the `spring-content-rest` dependency will cause Spring Content to also inject an implementation if an `@Controller` that forwards HTTP requests onto the method of the `FileStore`.

So you will now have a fully functional (POST, PUT, GET, DELETE) REST-based file service at `/files` that will use your `FileStore` to retrieve (and store) files in `/mnt`; i.e. on your remote SMB server.

So:

`GET /files/some/file.csv`

will download `file.csv` from `/path/to/your/files/some/`.

And...

`curl --upload-file some-other-file.csv /files/some-other-file.csv`

will upload `some-other-file.csv` and store it in `/mnt/` on your server.

And:

`curl /files/some-other-file.csv`

will retrieve it again.

HTH

The injected controller also supports video streaming too, in case that is useful.

Comment: thank you, @PaulWarren... I will give this a try and will post the results.

Comment: is there a way to specify a subdirectory at the time of uploading a file using Spring Content?  Some of the uploads we do are based on an row id and need to put all the related files under the same subdirectory.

Comment: @Jorge, yes.  if you uploaded to `/files/a/b/some-other-file.csv` then it would be stored in ``/mnt/a/b/some-other-file.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the  where you trying to save a MultipartFile that file is having the read and write permission linux machine.

Comment: Hi @iragond, I just updated the post.  The code is not failing, it is just performing very poorly.